# How to split response through server using regex

Tags: java, android, response

I want to split the response received through server so that I can take values ,and set on texts .. but i don't can take the values ...

response :  {"status":"no","requestCount":"0","estelamCount":"0"}

```
                    String[] split_model = response.split(",");
                  //  Log.i("split_model",split_model);
                    Log.i("phoneName", split_model[0]);
```

log == > I/phoneName: {"status":"no"

Comment: Does the server respond with {"status":"no","requestCount":"0","estelamCount":"0"} ? And if it does, you'd like to have it split like status:no, resquestCount:0, estelamCount:0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        String status ="";

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response); //convert to json

        if (jsonObject.has("status")){ //check if has the key
            status = jsonObject.getString("status"); // get the value
        }else{

        }

        Log.d("TAG", status); // do sth with the value

        //Log => status
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking about parsing your response and this is how you do it

```
JSONObject myJson = new JSONObject(response);

String status = myJson.optString("status");
String count = myJson.optString("requestCount");
String estelamCount = myJson.optString("estelamCount");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your receiving json data from server, so you can parse it as a json as previous answers pointed out. Even better, you can use Gson library to parse data as follows, 
1- create a class that represents your respose, you can use a tool like http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to acheive this, just paste your json string and then from the options on the right, choose Java as a target language, Json as source type, and Gson as annotation style, and enter any class name you want to use, the result should look like this 
package com.example;

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Response {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
public String status;
@SerializedName("requestCount")
@Expose
public String requestCount;
@SerializedName("estelamCount")
@Expose
public String estelamCount;
}
```

Then when you want to deal with the result, you can do it as follows

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
//now you can parse the response string you received, here is responseString
Response response = gson.fromJson(responseString, Response.class);
//now you can access any field using the response object 
Log.d("Reponse" , "status =  " + response.status  + ", requestCount = " + response.requestCount + ", estelamCount = " + response.estelamCount ;
```

Comment: Basil _ hi my friend  but i did use from Volley ..
 so i must delete the @SerializedName("status") and Expose.